# ERROR: COALESCE types bytea and timestamp without time zone cannot be matched

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql

I'm trying to run this query, but I'm getting this error:

```
 ERROR: COALESCE types bytea and timestamp without time zone cannot be matched
```

I guess the problem is on this line:

```
 COALESCE(:last_timestamp,date_trunc('hour', timestamp '1969-01-01 00:00:00.000000'))
```

the parameter:

```
:last_timestamp
```

can be NULL and this why I'm doing this cases

```
@Query(value="SELECT\n" +
      "  id,\n" +
      "  wristband_records_processed.device_id as deviceId,\n" +
      "  user_id as userId,\n" +
      "  rssi,\n" +
      "  record_timestamp as locationTimestamp,\n" +
      "  beacon_id as beaconId,\n" +
      "  locatable_devices.locatable_type as locatableType,\n" +
      "  coalesce(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (record_timestamp - lag(record_timestamp) OVER(order by record_timestamp))),0 )as duration\n" +
      " FROM wristband_records_processed\n" +
      "  LEFT JOIN locatable_devices on locatable_devices.device_id = wristband_records_processed.beacon_id\n" +
      "where user_id = :userId and record_type != 'HANDWASH'\n" +
      "      and rssi >= -85 AND locatable_type != 'UNKNOWN' AND wristband_records_processed.record_timestamp> COALESCE(:last_timestamp,date_trunc('hour', timestamp '1969-01-01 00:00:00.000000')) \n " +
      "OFFSET :offset LIMIT :limit ;", nativeQuery = true)
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: i tried many casting ways, but non of them work for me

Comment: Where is last_timestamp defined and set in the Spring code?

Comment: if its just the type, not the value - try `COALESCE(:last_timestamp::text::timestamptz` or even `COALESCE(to_timestamp(:last_timestamp::text)::timestamptz`

Answer (score 0):

just make them the same

```
COALESCE(date_trunc('hour', :last_timestamp ),
         date_trunc('hour', timestamp '1969-01-01 00:00:00.000000'))
```

or

```
COALESCE(:last_timestamp, timestamp '1969-01-01 00:00:00.000000')
```